# can't get application to work after namespacing

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone app that is working properly, however, when I tried to reorganize the code under a namespace I can't get it to do anything. I can't even trigger events (by clicking on ids)  for views that I know are getting initialized (through console log messages), so I'm wondering if I've introduced some fundamental flaw somehow. I'm following a pattern set out by this blog (in french) http://www.atinux.fr/2011/12/10/organiser-son-code-backbone-js-en-modules/

In the main application.js (see below), I instantiate all of the views and models after initiating the app on document ready. One change introduced as a result of creating this namespace was setting the models for the views with `this.models.game`

```
this.views.clock_view      = new this.Views.clockView({ model: this.models.game});
```

Inside the modules folder, I had a views.js and a models.js. I created each view and object like this, prefaced with `app.Views or app.Models` accordingly

```
app.Views.announceView = Backbone.View.extend({
 ....
app.Views.optionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
 ...
```

This app.Views.optionsView is getting initialized (according to a console.log statement in the initializer) but when I click on #new_game, the console.log in the startNewGame is not getting triggered

```
 'click #new_game': 'startNewGame'
      // 'click .action_button': 'startNewGame'

    },

    startNewGame: function() {
      console.log("startNewGame");
      this.model.new();
    },
```

As a result of the namespacing, one other key change I made was when I created new views inside one of the other views. Under the previous (non-namespaced app), I created individual question items from a  QuestionListView

```
    var view = new QuestionListItemView({ model: game });
```

but now I'm doing

```
 var view = new app.Views.questionListItemView({ model: app.models.game })
```

because the instance of the model was saved to `this.models.game` in application.js, however, I also tried using 'this.models.game'

```
   var view = new app.Views.questionListItemView({ model: this.models.game })
```

Either way, before the games model gets involved, I can't trigger the startNewGame function outlined above, so it's not solely an issue of how to identify the model.

I also wondered whether i should be using this.Views or app.Views after the 'new' when creating new views from within

```
  var view = new app.Views.questionListItemView({ model: this.models.game })
```

I'd be grateful if you could help me identify any flaws I've introduced.

application.js

```
var app = {
  // Classes
  Collections: {},
  Models: {},
  Views: {},
  // Instances
  collections: {},
  models: {},
  views: {},
  init: function () {
    this.models.game          = new this.Models.game();
    this.views.story_view     = new this.Views.storyView();  #doesn't have a model
    this.views.clock_view      = new this.Views.clockView({ model: this.models.game}); 
    this.views.field_view      = new this.Views.fieldView({ model: this.models.game});
    this.views.options_view    = new this.Views.optionsView({ model : this.models.game});
    this.views.announcement_view = new this.Views.announceView({ model: this.models.game});
    this.views.question_list_view      = new this.Views.questionListView({ model : this.models.game});
    this.views.question_list_item_view = new this.Views.questionListItemView({ model : this.models.game});
  }
};

$(document).ready(function () {

  app.init();
}) ;
```

The options view is getting initialized but I can't trigger the startNewGame function when I click that #id

```
app.Views.optionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // el: $("#options"),
    el: $("#options"),
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("app views OptionsView initialized");
      // this.model.bind("gameStartedEvent", this.removeGetAnswerButton, this);
      this.model.bind("gameStartedEvent", this.disableNewGame, this);

    },
    events: {
      'click #demo': 'startDemo',
      'click #new_game': 'startNewGame'
      // 'click .action_button': 'startNewGame'

    },
    startDemo: function(){
      console.log("start demo");
     this.model.demo();
    }, 
    startNewGame: function() {
      console.log("startNewGame");
      this.model.new();
    },
    disableNewGame: function(){
        $('#new_game').attr("disabled", true);
    }


  });
```

Update
My file structure looks like this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application.js'%>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'modules/models'%>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'modules/views'%>
```

At the top of the views and models file, I just do something like this

```
app.Views.optionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
```

ie.. there is no further document ready. In fact, including another document ready in these files breaks the application.js init

Comment: Things like `el: $("#options")` could be part of your problem. Are you sure that `#options` is in the DOM when you try to access it?

Comment: @muistooshort I thought that would have all been taken care of by initiating the app in the document ready. I don't know how to check if it's in the dom other than by using that document ready -- well I clicked on elements in the chrome console i can see #options..

Comment: `$('#options')` will be evaluated when the corresponding view gets parsed. As a rule of thumb, you should never say `el: $(...)` in a view definition, just use the selector and let Backbone convert it to a DOM node object later.

Comment: Sorry, instead of el: $('#options') what should I say?

Comment: @muistooshort that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: @muistooshort if you want to write an answer I'll accept and vote you up but for the time being I just repeated the information you gave me in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to using the namespace, I defined the element this way in the view

```
el: $("#options")
```

which, as was pointed out in the comments to this question, is not the ideal way to do it(see @muistooshort comment below), (even though it worked).

Defining the el this way instead

```
 el: '#options'
```

got it working, and let Backbone "convert it to a node object" on its own.